# htaccess 301 redirect based on referrer (if/else)

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have seen other answered questions explaining how to redirect users if the referrer matches one or more domains, but can't figure out how to do it in such a way that the person gets directed to site A if they are referred from domain B, and site C if they are referred from domain D.  All should be permanent redirects.

So here is the code I have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://domainB.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.websiteA.co [R=301,L]
```

I guess pseudo code would be something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
if (RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://domainB.com [NC]):
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.websiteA.co [R=301,L] 
else if (RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://domainD.com [NC]):
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.websiteC.co [R=301,L]
```

I also need to make sure it redirects everyone coming from that domain regardless of whether they are coming from the root or any other (sub)page.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the way Apache handles these conditions, you don't need an `if else` statement to get the desired behavior. As stated in the Apache [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html) documentation:

> One or more RewriteCond directives can be used to restrict the types
>   of requests that will be subject to the following RewriteRule.

Meaning a `RewriteRule` is only applied to a request if it matches the preceding `RewriteCond`, or if there is more than one `RewriteCond`, it must match them all.

> If more than one RewriteCond is specified, they must all match for the
>   RewriteRule to be applied.

As for your use of the `L` flag:

> **last|L**    Stop the rewriting process immediately and don't apply any
>   more rules.

This ensures your requests will not be processed by any further rules. Your conditions are mutually exclusive so a request wouldn't match both conditions anyway. This will allow you to write your .htaccess rules as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://domainB\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.websiteA.co$1 [R=301,L] 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://domainD\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.websiteC.co$1 [R=301,L]
```

This will result in any incoming request with `Referer: http://domainB.com` getting redirected to `https://www.websiteA.co` and any incoming request with `Referer: http://domainD.com` getting redirected to `https://www.websiteC.co`.

This will also cause the request URI to be preserved across redirects. If that is not desired, simply remove the `$1` tokens.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.  So if i wanted to have what would be an "else" at the the end as a third condition I could just add another equivalent line of "RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.websiteE.co$1 [R=301,L]" which would redirect everything that didn't match the previous 2 cases to this 3rd URL?

Comment: Yes, basically it would act as a catchall.